# libphp4 Not Found?

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, php

I'm using CentOS 6.5 and Apache 2.2.15

I've installed PHP 4.3.11 by download:

```
wget http://museum.php.net/php4/php-4.3.11.tar.gz
tar zxvf php-4.3.11.tar.gz
cd php-4.3.11
./configure
make
make install
```

It works, i can use php via command on terminal like this:

[image: php-v]

But when i run apache, it didn't show PHP language.

[image: trien8]

I've checked, that there're no modules libphp4.so and libphp4-zts.so

What wrong i did? Any help please...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to installing PHP you need to configure Apache so that it can make use of it. You can check by looking at Apache's `error_log`:

#### Module loading?

> $ more /var/log/httpd/error_log
>
> [Mon Feb 24 00:13:55.503116 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1818] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Fedora) PHP/5.5.8 configured -- resuming normal opera

If you see this, then Apache should be able to handle PHP pages. The only other thing you'll need to do is to tell Apache to use PHP to "handle" any pages that are named with the extension `.php`.

#### Handling .php files

The extension should "just work" out of the box since the CentOS version of Apache comes bundled with this file:

```
/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf
```

#### Loading the php4 modules

You will however need to reference your compiled versions of PHP here in a file similar to this one:

```
$ grep -i php /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/10-php.conf 
# PHP is an HTML-embedded scripting language which attempts to make it
  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5-zts.so
```

You'll need to point to your modules with lines like this:

```
LoadModule php4_module modules/libphp4.so
```

#### Testing it out

If I create the following file `/var/www/html/index.php`:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
echo "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

And I then load it in my browser like so, `http://localhost/index.php` I get the appropriate response:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Also I can confirm in Apache's `access_log` that the attempt was sucessful:

> ::1 - - [24/Feb/2014:00:17:46 -0500] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 53 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36"